# How to connect to a legacy Informix database?

Tags: informix

I have to connect my app to a customer's Informix 7.2 legacy database.

From what I was able to find out, in theory there should be a database service running on port 50000. The problem is that I cannot find any database service in the Operative System.

So far I'm only able to use dbaccess and perform queries from the command line.

I would like to use a database driver (such as http://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/) so my app can connect and query the database using a cursor, but since I cannot find any database service, apparently I can't...

Am I missing something here? Are there options I'm not considering?

Is it possible to have an Informix database in which the only interface is dbaccess?

Comment: Which tool are you using to connect to it? .NET, Java, etc?

Comment: I'm using Python, planning to connect with SQLAlchemy with the IBM driver (http://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/)

Comment: It seems that this driver works only with newer versions of Informix.

Comment: Do you have Client SDK installed on your machine? What operation system do you use?

Comment: The python app and the Informix server are on different machines. The python app is running on ubuntu. The Informix server is installed in a different machine (a very old Red Hat distro). I don't have permission to install anything on the Red Hat machine, so I have to connect remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Python you can look at: [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Informix) but I would like to extend it a little.

If you work on Windows and have Client SDK then there should be ODBC driver installed on your machine. There is also Linux and other unix versions of such client software. If you install that you can use ODBC to connect to database. On Windows you can use Active State Python 2.6 with win32 extensions which has `odbc` module included. On other Python implementations you can use win32 extensions or other ODBC module such as `mxODBC`.

I work also with Jython where I use both JDBC and ODBC drivers. You can see this "in action" in my SO questions like: [Problem with Informix JDBC Money format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020608/problem-with-informix-jdbc-money-and-decimal-separator-in-string-literals)

Comment: InfomixDB, mentioned in the python wiki, looks good, but I can't get it to install on the python app machine, since I don't have the Informix server there...
I need to do something remotely...
Haven't tried mxODBC yet...

Answer (score 2):

See [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/informix) for Informix

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if you want to connect to a remote legacy Informix database using Python from a Mac, [pypyodbc-informixcsdk](https://github.com/rockallite/pypyodbc-informixcsdk) could be your only (free) choice. Check [this wiki](https://github.com/rockallite/pypyodbc-informixcsdk/wiki/Connect-to-Informix-database-via-Python-on-OS-X-Mountain-Lion).

On a Windows box, [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) + [Informix Client SDK](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/search.jsp?rs=ifxdl) + [ODBC](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.odbc.doc/odbc62.htm) do the job nicely.