# JDBC/ODBC connection to Informix with Openoffice BASE on Windows 7. Will not show table lists

Tags: jdbc, odbc, informix, openoffice-base

I've attempted this with ODBC drivers, and JDBC drivers. I'll list both approaches separately.

ODBC approach

---

I'm using the ODBC driver found here: 
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/preconfig.jsp?id=2007-11-02+09%3A22%3A41.038818R&S_TACT=&S_CMP=

It's the Informix Connect 32bit program. I've tried the 64bit version, stand alone it will connect, but the ODBC will not work with OpenOffice (32bit to 64bit issue). I've then decided to use the 32 bit version.

After installing the ODBC driver, I used C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe to setup the driver in windows 7, it connected successfully.

Loading OpenOffice.org base I was able to use the ODBC to connect, but no tables are being listed. If I run a SQL query, I get this error:

```
SQL Status: HY106
Error code: -11086

[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Fetch type out of range.
```

JDBC approach

---

I can't use design view, since no tables are listed. Abandoning this, I used the JDBC driver, found here: 
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/preconfig.jsp?id=2005-03-09+16%3A56%3A12.268164R&S_TACT=&S_CMP=

This was more successful, but I still can't get tables to list. Here's the errors I get when I run the OpenOffice.org BASE file:

```
WARNING
SQL Status: 01I01

Database has transactions

ERROR
SQL Status: 01I04
Database selected
```

I don't understand how that would effect the JDBC so greatly. I can however execute SQL queries without a problem. I can't use design views.

In the end, all I'm trying to do is have a useful GUI that I can build and debug queries with. If OpenOffice.org is a poor choice, I'm still open to other options. But the opensource prospects are ideal.

Lastly, this isn't directly a programming question, is there a better forum I should be using?

Thanks

Comment: You might get a more rapid response on one of the IIUG (International Informix User Group) mailing lists.  See [http://www.iiug.org/](http://www.iiug.org/).  You would have to join to post to the lists, but that's free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for some general ODBC Editors/Designers.

I think that for JDBC there are more tools. You can use Eclipse with Data Tools Platform. Have a look at: [Database Development in Eclipse with the Data Tools Platform (DTP)](http://2tbsp.com/node/86) . It shows schema with tables, columns, etc.

I use simple ODBC editor done by myself for various ODBC tests but I also use Python with `odbc` module or even better Jython than can work with native JDBC drivers and ODBC drivers by JDBC-ODBC bridge. You can see such code at my SO questions like: [Problem with Informix JDBC, MONEY and decimal separator in string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020608/problem-with-informix-jdbc-money-and-decimal-separator-in-string-literals)

Comment: Thanks. This task got downgraded from really important, to something I'll do in my downtime (When will that be? ha!). I'll definitely look at it soon, because this looks promising. Thanks for the update.